# Can I console.log inside an async function before I return the data?

Tags: javascript, logging, console

I can't find a reply on Stackoverflow about this, but I would like to see what's happening to the data at each step of filtering and mapping
e.g. to `console.log` after each `.filter` and `.map`.

```
const printRestos = async () => {
  const instructorName = await getInstructorName();
  const restaurantType = await getRestaurantType();
  const address = await getAddress();
  const restaurants = await getRestaurants();
  const restos = restaurants
    .filter(row => row[0] === address)
    .filter(row => row[1] === restaurantType)
    .map(row => row[2]);
  lab.printRestoList(instructorName, restaurantType, address, restos);
};
printRestos();
```

Is that possible without breaking the code?
Thanks

I have tried to `console.log` but this breaks the code and also `peek` but it says it's not a valid function.

Comment: `restaurants.filter(row => { console.log(row); return row[0] === address; })`

Comment: _"I have tried to console.log but this breaks the code"_ - There's no such attempt in your question (or anything asynchronous at all) -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: Is this an RxJS question, or a Vanilla JS question?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following ways to do what you want:

1. Break-up the cool-looking fluent method chain, introduce intermediate variables, and then log these values.
2. Make your own `RestaurantCollection` type (with logging) by extending `Array`
3. Refactor the code to use a functional style for which filter and map can be composed together with a log function.
4. **Do not do this** Replace `Array#filter` **Do not do this**.
5. **Do not do this** Add a fluent log method to `Array.prototype`  **Do not do this**.

You should probably do (1.) because this is simplest to understand for other developers.

But I like playing around with functional concepts and so I include the following .

Note that the [pipeline operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator), which is a Stage 2 Proposal for ECMAScript, will add syntax support for this kind of thing.

```js
const log = (result) => (console.log(result), result)
const filter = (cb) => (arr) => arr.filter(cb)
const map = (cb) => (arr) => arr.map(cb)
const pipe = (...fns) => (arg) => fns.reduce((acc, f) => f(acc), arg)
   
const byCityAndType = (cityFilter, typeFilter) => ([city, type]) => city === cityFilter && type === typeFilter
const toName = ([,,name]) => name

const namesByCityAndType = (restaurants, city, type) => 
    pipe(filter(byCityAndType(city, type)), 
         log, 
         map(toName), 
         log)(restaurants)

const data = [ ['London', 'Cafe', 'Cafe Nero'],
               ['New York', 'Bistro', 'Lobster'],
               ['New York', 'Pizzeria', 'Pizza Hut'] ]

const result = namesByCityAndType(data, 'New York', 'Pizzeria')
console.log(`The result is: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
```

Comment: How does this (adding _"**Do not do this**"_ stuff) answer OPs question or solve _"I have tried to console.log but this breaks the code and also peek but it says it's not a valid function."_ which we only know of because of that text and not from an actual [mcve], and where's the _async_  part OP mentions in the title? Adding a simple `console.log()` in any of those callbacks is no black magic and doesn't break anything - when done correctly.

Comment: Oh hello, Andreas. Glad you continue to enjoy my responses! Note that adding a simple `console.log` to the callbacks will _not_ do what the OP is asking (hence their question).

Comment: We don't know what OP wants because there's no [mcve] with an actual `async` function or a `console.log()` call.

Comment: OP clearly has a couple of misunderstandings somewhere. eg. what is async. Which is fine with me. Maybe my answer will help them. Maybe the OP will come back and say that my answer is of no use: and that's fine too.

Comment: @BenAston I didn't think it mattered if I added more code since the `.filter` and `.map` can be used in different contexts, I have now added the whole functio but it's still a part of a bigger snippet. Does this suffice?

Comment: OK thanks. The async-ness doesn't change my answer in this instance, then.